# How to extract NSString from NSDictionary that contains nested JSON

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get NSStrings from an dictionary but the extracted strings contain the following

```
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x28205fc00>(
Aaron
)
```

I expected s plain NSString.

Code:

```
  NSString *name = [jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"users.fName"];
  NSLog(@"name, %@", name);
```

I though that using 'objectAtIndex' might work but it didn't.

Structure of NSDictionary (JSON) that I'm working with.

```
{
    TYPE = UPDATE;
    keys =     (
                {
            calendarId = b306db7e1f924fdebade3813dd596f5d;
            delFlag = 0;
            editTime = "2019-10-23T12:02:32.0857328";
            endTime = "2019-10-24T10:35:00";
            insId = 20;
            itemKeyId = 15;
            keyId = ce71bc7ae3c145adad18a72e56cf0fab;
            projectId = 950710ab2b96413cbfd186141e147b3e;
            startTime = "2016-05-23T21:10:00";
            updateStatus = 1;
            validateCount = 6;
        }
    );
    users =     (
                {
            calendarId = 0;
            delFlag = 0;
            editTime = "2019-10-23T12:02:32.0794244";
            fName = Aaron;
            insId = 20;
            itemUserId = 15;
            keyId = ce71bc7ae3c145adad18a72e56cf0fab;
            keyMac = 50338B11E912;
            lName = Joines;
            operId = 30222e0b4b0e4df6b669c3cf69245422;
            projectId = 950710ab2b96413cbfd186141e147b3e;
            userId = 8be21d1690bb46979a04b4e45a1ba625;
            userPin = 123456;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `NSString *name = [[jsonDict valueForKeyPath:@"users.fName"] first];` doesn't work?

Comment: @Larme no, I had tried that also.

Comment: But what is creating the output `<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x28205fc00>(`?  Could you show the JSON initial?

Comment: `[dict valueForKeyPath:@"users.fName"][0]` should work though (previously I meant `firstObject`, not `first`, doing too much Swift). Reproduced with sample `NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"users": @[@{@"fName": @"Name1"}]};`

Comment: @Larme, Thank you, that now makes sense....